# SSRS Report Subscription failed

Tags: reporting-services

I have SQL Server 2012 Standard edition. I have a report that is run and executes nearly 50% of the time, and I cannot seem to see a pattern why the report subscription is failing. If it failed all the time, it would be a little easier to track down the root cause.

The report is set to not timeout the report. Report Manager is also set to not timeout a report.

The timing is random. However, this is what I can extract from the log file.

email extension!WindowsService1!870! e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.

Thanks in advance for taking time to assist.

Marcus

Comment: Maybe you have intermittent network outages that make your smtp server unreachable temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I noticed after initiated a trace log that the report receives the notification in the above post after it has finished rendered, retrieved data and process the report.